# How to create a struct with two members, where the second is lifetime-dependent of the first?

Tags: rust, struct, borrow-checker

Suppose I have the following two structs:

```rust
struct Parent {
    name: String,
}
impl Parent {
    fn create_child(&self) -> Child {
        Child { parent_name: &self.name }
    }
}

struct Child<'a> {
    parent_name: &'a str,
}
```

Now I'm attempting to create the following struct:

```rust
struct Everyone<'a> {
    p: Parent,
    c: Child<'a>,
}
```

However, the borrow checker won't allow me to do this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let p = Parent { name: "foo".to_owned() };
    let c = p.create_child();
    let e = Everyone { p, c }; // error: p already borrowed!
}
```

How to properly write `Everyone` struct?

Comment: You don't. That's the answer.

Comment: Maybe a little more words: Rust is very strict on aliasing. Programming in Rust requires you to rethink some programming paradigms; many known solutions that work in other programming languages are not compatible with Rust. It's still worth it, though, because it usually leads to cleaner and better solutions in the end.